Apache POI Dependency in Maven Project : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.DocumentHelper
I want to export an xlsx file in a Java project, so I added the Apache POI libraries. However, it doesn't work. I removed the xerces dependency and it works, but it causes an error in the existing functions when I try to export to PDF format. I'm sharing with you the methods I use with the Apache POI libraries, as well as the pom.xml, the dependency tree, and the error descriptions.
I hope one of you can help me.
Thanks in advance.
the method export() :
   public ByteArrayOutputStream export() {
    CMIS2Logger.trace(CMIS2Logger.LEVEL_LOGGER_INFO, "Début de l'exportation du rapport");
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputByteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("First Sheet");

    try {
        Map<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Element>> columnsReportMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, CellStyle> cellStyles = new HashMap<>();

        // Créer les styles de cellules en dehors de la boucle principale
        createCellStyles(workbook, cellStyles);
        CMIS2Logger.trace(CMIS2Logger.LEVEL_LOGGER_INFO, "Styles de cellules créés");
        
        // Parcourir les rapports
        Iterator<String> itReportIDS = getCmis2JRDataSource().getMapReportIDColumns().keySet().iterator();
        while (itReportIDS.hasNext()) {
            String currentReportId = itReportIDS.next();
            CMIS2Logger.trace(CMIS2Logger.LEVEL_LOGGER_INFO, "Traitement du rapport ID: " + currentReportId);
            LinkedHashMap<String, Element> columnsReport = (LinkedHashMap<String, Element>) getCmis2JRDataSource().getMapReportIDColumns().get(currentReportId);
            columnsReportMap.put(currentReportId, columnsReport);

            // Créer les en-têtes de colonne
            createColumnHeaders(sheet, columnsReport, cellStyles);
            CMIS2Logger.trace(CMIS2Logger.LEVEL_LOGGER_INFO, "En-têtes de colonne créés pour le rapport ID: " + currentReportId);
            
            // Parcourir les enregistrements
            Iterator<?> itEnregistrement = getIteratorForReport(currentReportId);
            int idRow = 1;
            while (itEnregistrement.hasNext()) {
                Element current = (Element) itEnregistrement.next();
                List<Element> childsOfCurrent = current.getChildren();

                Row row = sheet.createRow(idRow++);
                int idCol = 0;
                for (Element node : childsOfCurrent) {
                    Element columnHeader = columnsReport.get(node.getName());
                    if (columnHeader != null) {
                        Cell cell = row.createCell(idCol++);
                        setCellValue(cell, columnHeader, node.getAttributeValue("value"), cellStyles);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        // Écrire le classeur Excel dans le ByteArrayOutputStream
        workbook.write(outputByteArray);
        CMIS2Logger.trace(CMIS2Logger.LEVEL_LOGGER_INFO, "Rapport exporté avec succès");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        CMIS2Logger.traceException(CMIS2Logger.LEVEL_LOGGER_ERROR,"Erreur lors de l'écriture du fichier Excel", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        CMIS2Logger.traceException(CMIS2Logger.LEVEL_LOGGER_ERROR, "Erreur lors de l'export du fichier Excel", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            workbook.close();
            CMIS2Logger.trace(CMIS2Logger.LEVEL_LOGGER_INFO, "Classeur Excel fermé avec succès");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            CMIS2Logger.traceException( CMIS2Logger.LEVEL_LOGGER_ERROR, "Erreur lors de la fermeture du fichier Excel", e);
        }
    }

    return outputByteArray;
}

the pom.xml :
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.5</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>itext</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fwk</groupId>
        <artifactId>fwk</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2b2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fwk</groupId>
        <artifactId>fwk-jndi</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2b1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.atos.mm.fwk</groupId>
        <artifactId>sysmm</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxp-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>atos</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>atos</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fwk</groupId>
        <artifactId>fwk-admin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0b2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fwk</groupId>
        <artifactId>fwk-opm</artifactId>
        <version>3-2-0b1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atosorigin.awl.fwk_home.lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>fw3</artifactId>
        <version>1-4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.atos.mm.fwk</groupId>
        <artifactId>fw3-tools</artifactId>
        <version>1-0-0b2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atosorigin.awl.jar_home.regexp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta-oro</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4c</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.awl.reporting</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-rpc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <classifier>awl</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jxl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.org.jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3_compile</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xmlParserAPIs</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlParserAPIs</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.octo.captcha</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcaptcha</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

the dependecies tree :
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:5.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.15.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.zaxxer:SparseBitSet:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:5.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-lite:jar:5.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:5.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.25.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:jar:1.08:compile
[INFO] +- itext:itext:jar:4.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:3.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:jar:136:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:136:compile
[INFO] |  +- jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.02:compile
[INFO] |  \- eclipse:jdtcore:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- fwk:fwk:jar:2.1.2b2:compile
[INFO] +- fwk:fwk-jndi:jar:1.1.2b1:compile
[INFO] +- net.atos.mm.fwk:sysmm:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.xml:jaxp-api:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- atos:jmxri:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- atos:jmxtools:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- fwk:fwk-admin:jar:2.0.0b2:compile
[INFO] +- fwk:fwk-opm:jar:3-2-0b1:compile
[INFO] +- com.atosorigin.awl.fwk_home.lib:fw3:jar:1-4:compile
    [INFO] +- net.atos.mm.fwk:fw3-tools:jar:1-0-0b2:compile
    [INFO] +- com.atosorigin.awl.jar_home.regexp:jakarta-oro:jar:2.0.5:compile
    [INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.1.2:compile
    [INFO] +- taglibs:standard:jar:1.1.2:compile
    [INFO] +- com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar:4.2:compile
    [INFO] +- xpp3:xpp3:jar:1.1.4c:compile
    [INFO] +- net.awl.reporting:json-rpc:jar:awl:1.0:compile
    [INFO] +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
    [INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
    [INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
    [INFO] +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
    [INFO] +- jxl:jxl:jar:2.6.9:compile
    [INFO] +- org.jaxen:com.springsource.org.jaxen:jar:1.1.3_compile:compile
    [INFO] +- xmlParserAPIs:xmlParserAPIs:jar:5.0.0:compile
    [INFO] +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
    [INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile
    [INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.1:compile
    [INFO] +- xerces:xerces:jar:1.4.4:compile
    [INFO] +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.7.1:compile
    [INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api:jar:2.17.1:compile
    [INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.1:compile
    [INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.17.1:compile
    [INFO] +- com.octo.captcha:jcaptcha:jar:1.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- com.octo.captcha:jcaptcha-api:jar:1.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- com.jhlabs:imaging:jar:01012005:compile
    [INFO] |  \- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.3:compile
    [INFO] +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.2:compile
    [INFO] |  \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.2:compile
    [INFO] \- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.7:compile
    [INFO]    \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile

The error message :
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.DocumentHelper
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ContentTypeManager.save(ContentTypeManager.java:429)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:608)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.save(OPCPackage.java:1532)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.close(OPCPackage.java:506)
at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.close(POIXMLDocument.java:189)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.close(XSSFWorkbook.java:640)
at cmis2.generation.renderer.JRRendererXLSX.export(JRRendererXLSX.java:95)
at cmis2.application.filtres.FileFilter.downloadForReports(FileFilter.java:387)
at cmis2.application.filtres.FileFilter.doFilter(FileFilter.java:228)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:179)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:154)
at cmis2.application.filtres.FiltreRIGHTS.doFilter(FiltreRIGHTS.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:179)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:154)
at cmis2.application.filtres.FiltreLOGUE.doFilter(FiltreLOGUE.java:105)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:179)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:670)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1786)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 
 


you most likely do not want any xerces or xalan dependencies.  it's been a long time since you needed external xml processors with java.  many old projects still have those as optional dependencies, but all that functionality is built into the jdk these days.  your best bet is to remove all of that.  (ditch xml-apis and jaxp-api while you are at it)

First of all, thank you for your reply. Yes, this project is old, and I think that if I remove the xerces and xalan dependencies, it will create new problems because these dependencies are used in the existing project.

what version of java are you using
